# set spinner blank if jsonarray is null

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

I've 2 APIs and two spinners: one for state's list and another for city's list. In some cases the city list's JSONArray might be null. So I want to check in volley's JSON parsing if its null then set some default message in spinner. But its not showing the default message. Instead its showing the city list of the state which is by default set. Is there any solution for this?

```js
// null city list

{
  "citylist": []
}
```

```css
// JSON for state list

{
  "statelist": [
    {
      "state_id": "1",
      "state_name": "West bengal"
    },
    {
      "state_id": "3",
      "state_name": "Himachal Pradesh"
    },
    {
      "state_id": "4",
      "state_name": "Maharashtra"
    },
    {
      "state_id": "11",
      "state_name": "Queensland"
    }
  ]
}
```

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String STATE = "http://example.com/ubooktoday/android/showstatebycountry";
    private static final String CITY = "http://example.com/ubooktoday/android/showcitybystate";
    Spinner spin1, spin2;
    String stateid, cityid, zipid;
    ArrayList<String> namelist, idlist;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    HashMap<String,String> spinnerMap1, spinnerMap2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spin1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin1);
        spin2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin2);

        namelist = new ArrayList<String>();
        idlist = new ArrayList<String>();

        loadstate();

        spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String statename = spin1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                stateid = spinnerMap1.get(statename);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), stateid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadcity();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });

        spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String cityname = spin2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                cityid = spinnerMap2.get(cityname);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cityid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });



    }



    private void loadstate() {

        if(namelist!=null )namelist.clear();
        if(idlist!=null )idlist.clear();


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, STATE,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {

                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);

                            JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("statelist");
                            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                                namelist.add(obj.getString("state_name"));
                                idlist.add(obj.getString("state_id"));

                                String[] spinnerArray = new String[idlist.size()];
                                spinnerMap1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < idlist.size(); j++)
                                {
                                    spinnerMap1.put(namelist.get(j),idlist.get(j));
                                    spinnerArray[j] = namelist.get(j);
                                }

                                adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

                                spin1.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "VolleyError" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("country_id", "2");
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void loadcity() {

        if(namelist!=null )namelist.clear();
        if(idlist!=null )idlist.clear();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, CITY,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);

                            JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("citylist");

                            if(jsonArray.equals("null")){
                                namelist.add("No Items");

                                adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, namelist);
                                spin2.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }else{

                                for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

                                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                                    namelist.add(obj.getString("city_name"));
                                    idlist.add(obj.getString("city_id"));

                                    String[] spinnerArray = new String[idlist.size()];
                                    spinnerMap2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                    for (int j = 0; j < idlist.size(); j++)
                                    {
                                        spinnerMap2.put(namelist.get(j),idlist.get(j));
                                        spinnerArray[j] = namelist.get(j);
                                    }

                                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
                                    spin2.setAdapter(adapter);
                                }

                            }





                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // JSON error
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "VolleyError" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("state_id", stateid);
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code for checking json array condition,

```
  if(jsonArray == null || jsonArray.equals("null") || jsonArray.length <= 0)
  {
       namelist.add("No Items");

       adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, namelist);
       spin2.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

Comment: Hi. There is one another problem. If the 1st spinner is set `No Items` using above code, how to set the 2nd spinner's value also as `No Items`? @Vickyexpert

Comment: when you set no items for first spinner at same time apply above code for 2nd spinner also as no items

Comment: I did exactly. I made a method which returns arrayadapter value and I added this value in spinner. Thanks.

Comment: OK Enjoy your coding, You can upvote this answer if it helps you